# Get array json data

Tags: php, json, rest, httpresponse, slim

I use the Slim framework for a REST API. My `tasks` route is defined as:

```
$app->get('/tasks', 'authenticate', function() {
    global $user_id;
    $response = array();
    $items = array();
    $db = new DbHandler();
    $result = $db->getAllUserTasks($user_id);
    if ($result != NULL) {
        foreach ($result as $rez) {
            $response["error"] = false;
            $response["id"] = $rez["id"];
            $response["task"] = $rez["task"];
            $response["status"] = $rez["status"];
            $response["createdAt"] = $rez["created_at"];
            $items[] = $response;
        }
        echoRespnse(200, $items);  
    } else {
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["message"] = "The requested resource doesn't exists";
        echoRespnse(404, $response);
    }              
});
```

I want this kind of json response :

```
{
"error": false,
"tasks": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "task": "Complete test1",
        "status": 0,
        "createdAt": "2014-01-08 23:35:45"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "task": "Complete test2",
        "status": 0,
        "createdAt": "2014-01-08 23:56:52"
    }
]
}
```

Instead, I get something like :

`[1] 0: { error: false "2" task: "2" status: "2" createdAt: "2" }`

What is wrong with my route?

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to format your array like below 
     if ($result != NULL) {
        $response["error"] = false;
        foreach ($result as $rez) { 
          $arr =array();
          $arr["id"] = $rez["id"];
          $arr["task"] = $rez["task"];
          $arr["status"] = $rez["status"];
          $arr["createdAt"] = $rez["created_at"];  
          $response['task'][] = $arr; 
        }
      }
     $item = $response;
```

Comment: Thanks ,but now I get wrong data like this : `[1]
0:  {
error: false
task: [8]
0:  {
id: 11
}-
1:  {
task: "hhhhhhhhh"
}-
2:  {
status: 0
}-
3:  {
createdAt: "2015-03-20 04:56:30"
}-
4:  {
id: 12
}-
5:  {
task: "hhhhhhhhhnnnnnnn"
}-
6:  {
status: 0
}-
7:  {
createdAt: "2015-03-20 04:57:50"
}-
-
} `

Comment: same error `[1]
0:  {
error: false
task: [26]
0:  {
id: 11
task: "hhhhhhhhh"
status: 0
createdAt: "2015-03-20 04:56:30"
}-
1:  {
id: 12
task: "hhhhhhhhhnnnnnnn"
status: 0
createdAt: "2015-03-20 04:57:50"
}-
2:  {
id: 13
task: "-7,643060"
status: 0
createdAt: "2015-03-21 05:39:47"
} `

Comment: @David Did you tried to look at the function that writes the response. Maybe the issue is in there. What that `echoResponse` function does?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the php function `json_encode()` ?
I think you are not creating a JSON string, you are probably just outputting an array.

```
<?php
// your array with the JSON data
// (associative array)
// each array key is a json property and each array value is a json value.
$arr =array();
$arr["id"] = $rez["id"];
$arr["task"] = $rez["task"];
$arr["status"] = $rez["status"];
$arr["createdAt"] = $rez["created_at"];  

echo json_encode($arr); // this outputs a valid JSON string.
```

Maybe you can try the above code.
And I think your current problem is in your echoRespnse function.